# Set environment variables on ssh session and be kept after logout

Tags: linux, ssh, environment-variables

I want to understand how can I set some environment variables on a remote session that are kept even after i logout and login again afterwards.

So,what i normally do

userssh@sshserver:~> export TEST=test/test
userssh@sshserver:~> env | grep TEST
TEST=test/test''

log out
log back in

userssh@sshserver:~> env | grep TEST 
userssh@sshserver:~>

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have two type login

Login shell >> conosle direct on system

Non login shell >> ssh,telent and remote shell

Inside of them we have two configuration
Profile for login shell
bash.bashrc for non login shell

If you put configuration on these files , everytime console or terminal logged it will be execute

In your scenario you must set environment varible in bashrc file which in new distru it changed to environment under

```
/etc/environment
```

OR

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```